# Список ip в Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle

Я программист  PL/SQL. 
Офисc.  Локальная сеть. сеть в домене.  На сервере с Windows 2018 R2,  установлен  Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.

```
(
SELECT * FROM v$version
WHERE banner LIKE 'Oracle%';
)
```

В локальной сети серверу присвоен ip 172.20.0.10.
Другой компьютер из локальной сети, ip 172.20.0.154, Windows 10 Pro 64, oracle client 11g, 11.2.0.1.0, Toad for Oracle Xpert (64-bit).
Когда подключаюсь к базе (Oracle Database 11g Enterprise (172.20.0.10) с (172.20.0.154), 
Администратор видит ip  компьютера 172.20.0.10 в (enterprise manager oracle 11g) или  в базе.
Я тоже могу видеть через

```
(
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')  CLIENT_IP

    FROM dual)
```

например.

К интернету у моего компьютера доступ через прокси. И есть разные ограничения.
Я установил OpenVPN, хочу создать VPN  c домашним компьютером.

У меня вопрос, админ будет видеть только IP  моего компьютера в локальной сети (172.20.0.154,) 
или еще ip  от opnvpn 10.10.10.2 ?
Администратор СУБД Oracle, еcли я подключен к базе Oracle и у меня  запущен OpenVPN  моему компьютеру присвоен еще один IP, какие IP увидит Администратор СУБД ?

Буду точнее.
Не администратор сети а администратор базы данных (Oracle).

Comment: Ваш админ будет видеть только то IP,  с которым осуществлён коннект к прослушивателю базы.

Comment: Буду точнее.
Не администратор сети а администратор базы данных (Oracle).

Comment: Я его и имел ввиду.

Answer (score 0):

Если запустить и  этот запрос

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (
   SELECT 'ACTION' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'ACTION') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------


   SELECT 'AUDITED_CURSORID' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'AUDITED_CURSORID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


   SELECT 'AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   SELECT 'AUTHENTICATION_METHOD' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATION_METHOD') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   SELECT 'AUTHENTICATION_METHOD' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATION_TYPE') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'BG_JOB_ID' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'BG_JOB_ID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'CLIENT_IDENTIFIER' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CLIENT_IDENTIFIER') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'CLIENT_INFO' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CLIENT_INFO') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   SELECT 'CURRENT_BIND' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_BIND') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'CURRENT_SCHEMA' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'CURRENT_SCHEMAID' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMAID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'CURRENT_SQL' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SQL') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'CURRENT_SQL_LENGTH' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SQL_LENGTH') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'CURRENT_USER' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'CURRENT_USERID' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USERID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'DB_DOMAIN' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'DB_DOMAIN') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'DB_NAME' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'DB_NAME') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'DB_UNIQUE_NAME' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'DB_UNIQUE_NAME') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'ENTRYID' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'ENTRYID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'ENTERPRISE_IDENTITY' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'ENTRYID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'FG_JOB_ID' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'FG_JOB_ID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'GLOBAL_CONTEXT_MEMORY' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'GLOBAL_CONTEXT_MEMORY') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'GLOBAL_UID' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'GLOBAL_UID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'HOST' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'HOST') PARAM FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'IDENTIFICATION_TYPE' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'IDENTIFICATION_TYPE') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'INSTANCE' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'INSTANCE') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'INSTANCE_NAME' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'INSTANCE_NAME') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'IP_ADDRESS' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'ISDBA' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'ISDBA') PARAM FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SELECT 'LANG' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'LANG') PARAM FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'LANGUAGE' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'LANGUAGE') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'MODULE' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'MODULE') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'NETWORK_PROTOCOL' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'NETWORK_PROTOCOL') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'NLS_CALENDAR' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'NLS_CALENDAR') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'NLS_CURRENCY' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'NLS_CURRENCY') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'NLS_SORT' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'NLS_SORT') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'NLS_TERRITORY' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'NLS_TERRITORY') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'OS_USER' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'POLICY_INVOKER' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'POLICY_INVOKER') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'PROXY_ENTERPRISE_IDENTITY' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'PROXY_ENTERPRISE_IDENTITY') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'PROXY_USER' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'PROXY_USER') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'PROXY_USERID' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'PROXY_USERID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'SERVER_HOST' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SERVER_HOST') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'SESSION_USER' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'SESSION_USERID' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USERID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'SESSIONID' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSIONID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'SID' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SID') PARAM FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'STATEMENTID' Parameter,
          SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'STATEMENTID') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'TERMINAL' Parameter, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'TERMINAL') PARAM
     FROM DUAL
     )

     WHERE 
     PARAM IS NOT NULL
```

Он выдает

```
AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY  USER_BANCU
AUTHENTICATION_METHOD   PASSWORD
AUTHENTICATION_METHOD   DATABASE
CURRENT_SCHEMA  USER_BANCU
CURRENT_SCHEMAID    113
CURRENT_USER    USER_BANCU
CURRENT_USERID  113
DB_NAME BNSDB
DB_UNIQUE_NAME  BNSDB
FG_JOB_ID   0
GLOBAL_CONTEXT_MEMORY   0
HOST    INTERN\DTI-103-3
IDENTIFICATION_TYPE LOCAL
INSTANCE    1
INSTANCE_NAME   bnsdb
IP_ADDRESS  172.20.1.154
ISDBA   FALSE
LANG    US
LANGUAGE    AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
MODULE  TOAD 11.6.0.43
NETWORK_PROTOCOL    tcp
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
OS_USER INTERN\VitalieBancu
SERVER_HOST server-db
SESSION_USER    USER_BANCU
SESSION_USERID  113
SESSIONID   93934683
SID 117
TERMINAL    DTI-103-3
```